# Find limit :$\lim_{n\rightarrow＋\infty}\sum_{k＝1}^{n}\frac {1}{k(k＋1)(k＋1)!}$

Tags: limits, summation

**Question :**

Find limit : $$\lim_{n\rightarrow＋\infty}\sum_{k＝1}^{n}\frac {1}{k(k＋1)(k＋1)!}$$

---

**My attemp:**
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow＋\infty}\sum_{k＝1}^{n}\frac {1}{k(k＋1)(k＋1)!}=\lim_{n\rightarrow＋\infty}\sum_{k＝1}^{n}\left(\frac {1}{k}－\frac {1}{k＋1}\right)\cdot\frac {1}{(k＋1)!}$$

---

> **I appreciate your help**

Comment: Your attempt looks like the start of something interesting... Did you maybe mean to continue by making the second term include $\frac {k+2}{(k+2)!}$?

Comment: Hint: write $\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\int_0^1\int_0^1x^{k-1}y^kdxdy$, substitute $z=xy$, then reverse the order of integration. You should get $3-e$.

Comment: Splitting (in 3 pieces) is a good strategy: 
$\frac{1}{k(k＋1)(k＋1)!}=\frac{(k+1)^2-k-k(k+1)}{k(k＋1)(k＋1)!}=\frac {1}{kk!}-\frac {1}{(k＋1)(k+1)!}-\frac {1}{(k+1)!}.$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following Robert's Hint $$\frac{1}{k(k＋1)(k＋1)!}=\frac{(k+1)^2-k-k(k+1)}{k(k＋1)(k＋1)!}=\frac {1}{kk!}-\frac {1}{(k＋1)(k+1)!}-\frac {1}{(k+1)!}$$ So our question becomes $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{kk!}-\frac {1}{(k＋1)(k+1)!}-\frac {1}{(k+1)!}$$ You can see that the first two terms telescope so we're left with $$1-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)!}$$
$$=1-\left(\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\cdots\right)$$ Recall that $$e=\left(\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\cdots\right)$$
So $$1-\left(\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\cdots\right)=1-(e-2)$$ $$\boxed{=3-e}$$